# JND InvalidSearchFilterException - How can I search LDAP for canonical name?

Tags: java, powershell

I'm trying to retrieve the email address set in Active Directory to a specified canonical name via JND. I tried the same process with other parameters (e. g. sAMAccountName, principal name or mail) before, but this time, it doesn't work.

```
initializeLDAP();
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(canonicalName=" + name + "))";
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
String returnedAttributes[] = { "mail" };
searchControls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAttributes);
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);
SearchResult searchResult = null;
searchResult = results.nextElement();

if (searchResult.getAttributes().get("mail") != null
                    && searchResult.getAttributes().get("mail").get() != null) {
    logger.info("mail to canonical name {} is {}", name,
    searchResult.getAttributes().get("mail").get());
                mail = (String) 

searchResult.getAttributes().get("mail").get();
   ...}
```

I get the following exception on this line `NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);`

```
javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: [LDAP: error code 18 - 0000216B: AtrErr: DSID-031404E3, #1:
    0: 0000216B: DSID-031404E3, problem 1004 (WRONG_MATCH_OPER), data 0, Att 90394 (canonicalName)
```

I'd rather search for a different parameter but unfortunately the canonical name is all that I've got from a powershell script output. So is there an other way to search for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.

I read about canonical name being a composed attribute and therefore nor searchable.
I cut the canonical name string after the last `/` and used this to search for `cn` which works fine.